# Working with bad code ? do i need to refactor it?

Tags: refactoring

I'm working in company with a big system with a messy code structure. I want to work with the right standards like polymorphism and design patterns.

But the code is such a mess and needs to be heavily refactored to do that. Also my current company gives me tasks, and if I have would heavily refactor, that will open many bugs in the system as it's not unit tested, of course.

What do you think? Should I work on the tasks on this bad structure to finish the work? Or tell them that we need rebuild many things (also they won't find a difference as the features already work now).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to start off with some unit tests.

Whilst doing the tasks you have been assigned, you could write some tests to test the code you are about to change, then you can refactor it.

Now you can start to write the code for your task, test-first.

If the code that is already there works, then refactoring is the best option. If it doesn't work, then a rewrite becomes possible.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Refactoring without sufficient testing capabilities is suicidal. No company would want new bugs in exchange to a nice code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Well...you need to work on multiple aspects.

First, learn best practices to write clean code (if you haven't yet) and request your team members the same. There are many useful books and online resources available for the same.

Second, do not expect that the situation will change overnight. Adopt "[Boy scout rule](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Boy_Scout_Rule)" - it will gradually improve the code quality.

Third, start building your corpus of unit tests. Slowly, testable code will emerge out of the sea of untestable monolith.